# Custom views inside FrameLayout issue in Picture-in-picture RTL layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, right-to-left, android-framelayout, android-picture-in-picture

I have a full screen `FrameLayout` which contains four Views that I add at runtime:

[image: Full screen LTR FrameLayout]

```kotlin
repeat(4) { i ->
    val view = View(this).apply {
        setBackgroundColor(COLOR[i])
    }
    views += view
    container.addView(view)
}
```

and to handle Picture-in-picture mode size change I've implemented `onSizeChanged` method:

```kotlin
container = object : FrameLayout(this) {
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        resizeViews(w, h)
    }
}
```

and resize my views according to new width and height:

```
private fun resizeViews(width: Int, height: Int) {
    val isRtl = resources.configuration.layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
    val rtlFactor = if (isRtl) -1.0F else 1.0F

    views.forEachIndexed { i, view ->
        val x = width * LAYOUT[i].first * rtlFactor
        val y = height * LAYOUT[i].second
        val w = width / 2
        val h = height / 2
        val layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h)

        view.x = x
        view.y = y
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

    container.post {
        container.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

here are my consts:

```kotlin
    companion object {
        private val LAYOUT = listOf(
            0.0F to 0.0F,
            0.5F to 0.0F,
            0.0F to 0.5F,
            0.5F to 0.5F,
        )

        private val COLOR = listOf(
            Color.RED,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.BLUE,
        )
    }
```

[image: PiP size LTR FrameLayout]

BUT after switching to RTL layout the PiP window start acting differently:

[image: PiP size RTL FrameLayout]

Layout inspector shows that my views has been drawn somewhere off the screen

[image: PiP size RTL in Layout inspector]

and when I return to full screen from PiP this happens:

[image: Full size RTL FrameLayout]

I've logged all size calculations and there is no difference between LTR and RTL mode except negative value for Xs since it is how it works in Android.

I also tried different solutions like removing all views and adding them again with the new layout option, or posting `requestLayout` on every view and none of them worked.

Any comment or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find the root cause or a proper solution.

I was lucky that my inner layouts had no UI element that required to be drawn RTL and therefore I switched my layout direction to LTR at runtime and it works fine:

```
container.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
```

But still looking for the reason and a proper fix.